# Rails: first_or_create not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

Very strange issue with first_or_create. Consider the following method:

```
def self.store(session)
    shop = self.first_or_create(shopify_domain: session.url, shopify_token: session.token)

    binding.pry

    shop.save!
    shop.shopify_domain
  end
```

When I pry into this method, I can call `session.url` to get `domain2.myshopify.com`  and `session.token` to get `22222`

But when I call shop, I get a shop where `shopify_domain: domain1.myshopify.com` and `shopify_token: 11111`.

Any idea why this would happen? It seems bizarre.

Comment: You can either do `shop = self.find_or_create_by(shopify_domain: session.url, shopify_token: session.token)` or follow penner's answer. What `first_or_create` means is: try to take the first element from the caller scope (in your case self) and if it returned nil, create an instance from the input parameters

Comment: Lost 30 minutes on this. Thanks for this question, I also had misunderstood the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
shop = self.where(shopify_domain: session.url, shopify_token: session.token).first_or_create(shopify_domain: session.url, shopify_token: session.token)
```

You are just getting the first one in general. Like calling .all.first